# Change the headers (user-agent) of Vitamio Library for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, vitamio

I'm currently developing an Live TV streaming app for iOS, using Vitamio Library to play the streams.

According to [Vitamio's documentation](http://yixia.github.io/Vitamio-iOS/Classes/VMediaPlayer.html#class_methods), you can set the media url to media player, and also pass protocol header to it.

How should I modify the following code, in order to send headers, more specifically (User-Agent: myuseragent).

```
[mMPayer setDataSource:fileURL header:nil];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am facing same issue let me know if have done this work